# My labels in an instanced object are disappearing

Tags: java, swing

***EDIT - I have removed all of the unnecessary code (I thought it might be useful for someone to see the steps I have taken to troubleshoot)

I am having a very odd issue. I am instantiating an object with multiple swing objects but the jlabel on all but the very last instance disappears. They are all the same but only the the highest numbered array index has its label showing. But they all should be seen. I have verified that they are in the correct position and have the correct size and it is set to visible but I cannot figure out why this is happening. I have run the program on another computer and it had the same results. There are two classes only. It is a pretty simple program but I can't seem to figure this one out, can some run this code and let me know if it works? if not can someone identify the issue?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class sizer extends JPanel {
    public static int lhval = 10000;
    public static int lvval = 10000;
    public static int shval = 10000;
    public static int svval = 10000;
    public static String IDlbltxt = "0";
    public static int IDlblint = 0;
    static boolean DEBUG = true;

    public final static JLabel IDlbl = new JLabel( "0" );

    public sizer (int arg) {
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(91, 88);
        setVisible( true );

        IDlbltxt = Integer.toString(arg);
        IDlblint = arg;

        IDlbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        IDlbl.setLocation( 40 , 30 );
        IDlbl.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        IDlbl.setText( IDlbltxt );
        IDlbl.setVisible(true);
        IDlbl.setBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 5) );
        IDlbl.setSize( IDlbl.getPreferredSize() );
        add( IDlbl );


        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame( "sizer - gettin it sized" );
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(320, 260);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setVisible( true );
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.red );


        final sizer s1 = new sizer(0);
        s1.setLocation( 1, 1);
        frame.add(s1);

        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

here is the second file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class sizerist extends JPanel {
    final static sizer[] sizing = new sizer[21];

    public sizerist () {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame( "sizer - gettin it sized" );
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(320, 260);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setVisible( true );
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.red );


        for (int i=1; i<6; i++) {
            sizing[i] = new sizer(1);
            if (i == 1) {
                sizing[i].setLocation( 1, 1);
            } else {
                sizing[i].setLocation( sizing[i-1].getLocation().x, sizing[i-1].getLocation().y  + sizing[i-1].getSize().height + 2); 
            }
            frame.add(sizing[i]);
            frame.setSize(sizing[i].getSize().width + sizing[i].getLocation().x, sizing[i].getSize().height + sizing[i].getLocation().y + 40);
        }

        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make your code easier to read that you're not using Java standards for naming (PascalCase for classes and camelCase for variables).

Comment: Null layouts aren't going to help you. if (true) and if (false) make no sense

Comment: Call frame.setVisible(true) last, after you've built the UI

Comment: There's *way* too much code here; you need to post the minimal case necessary to demonstrate the issue. For heaven's sake, you have large unreachable code blocks included! That said, this bug usually points to reusing an object somewhere instead of actually creating and using a new one.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I use if (true) / false to quickly block out code when I don't need to see it. I use Null layout because I need specific placement of objects, not all objects were included for sake of size. I tried putting frame.setVisible(true) last but still no joy.

Comment: @chrylis I thought I had removed all unreachable code but I did remove it this time. Each element in the array receives its own new object, but only the last element shows the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a series of problems...

```
public static String IDlbltxt = "0";
public static int IDlblint = 0;
static boolean DEBUG = true;

public final static JLabel IDlbl = new JLabel( "0" );
```

`static` is not your friend.  Basically, when you create the first instance of `sizer`, these `static` variables are initialised, they are never initialised again.

A component can only reside within a single container, meaning that each time you call `add(IDlbl);` it is first removed from it's current container before been added to the new container (or the last instance of `sizer`)

`static` is not a mechanism for cross object communications, get use to passing references and using setters and getters

Your `sizer` class has a `main` method, not an issue, just a point of confusion...

Call `frame.setVisible(true);` last, AFTER you have added all you components to the window.

[image: Layout]

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Because you've chosen to do away with layout managers, you are going to have no end of issues updating the UI, as any of the techniques that would normally work, probably won't work or will work intermittently.

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: removing the static fixed the issue, normally the compiler barks at me demanding I put it in. I will see in the morning with the other components if it barks again. Thanks for working with me to get to the bottom of this.